# AVX512 perform AND of 512bits of 8-bit chars

Tags: c++, x86, bitwise-operators, intrinsics, avx512

I'd like to AND two vectors of 512 bits containing 8 bit elements.

Looking at the Intel Intrinsics Guide I can see some 512-bit AND operations:

```
__m512i _mm512_and_epi32 (__m512i a, __m512i b)
__m512i _mm512_and_epi64 (__m512i a, __m512i b)
```

but nothing for epi8 (or epi16).

Is it safe to use the epi64? My only hesitation is why they have provided both epi32 and epi64, presumably both could use epi32. Performance reasons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are just simple bitwise AND; you can use either on any data.
Or better, **use `_mm512_and_si512` which has the desired semantic meaning.**

In asm, `vpandd` and `vpandq` can be used with masking at 32-bit or 64-bit granularity, respectively.  Masking is the only reason for having separate opcodes, unlike with AVX2 and earlier where there was just `vpand` (`_mm256_and_si256` and `_mm_and_si128`).

Without a mask, there's no significance to the element width.  The only reason for `_mm512_and_epi32` and `epi64` to exist at all is for consistency with `_mm512_mask[z]_and_epi[32|64]`.

`_mm512_and_si512` exists, and will compile to either `vpandq` or `vpandd`.
[The intrinsics guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=MMX,SSE_ALL,AVX_ALL,AVX_512,Other&ig_expand=796,3668,307&text=and_si) says it's nominally an intrinsic for `vpandd`.
IIRC, most compilers favour wider elements and will pick `vpandq` like how they use `vmovdqa64` for `_mm512_load_si512`.  If they don't fold it into a `vpternlogq` with some other bitwise booleans on the same data.

AVX512BW added EVEX versions of instructions like `vpaddb` where element width matters even without masking.  But didn't add byte or word mask widths for bitwise booleans, only [`vmovdqu8` / `vmovdqu16`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movdqu:vmovdqu8:vmovdqu16:vmovdqu32:vmovdqu64) (and [`vpblendmb`/`vpblendmw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpblendmb:vpblendmw)) for separate load, store, or reg-reg blend (merge-masking) or zero-masking.

For 128 and 256-bit vector widths, hopefully most compilers will use AVX2 `vpand` for `_mm256_and_epi32` if the data is in YMM0-15 (instead of YMM16-31).

---

Fun fact: `vandps/pd` wasn't part of AVX512F (foundation), only integer `vpandd/q` were in that. The FP versions were added as part of AVX512DQ.
(Xeon Phi is the only real hardware that has AVX512F without AVX512BW and DQ, and fewer redundant opcodes saves transistors in the decoders I guess, and I guess it didn't care about separate SIMD-int vs. FP domains for bypass forwarding.  [AVX-512](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#CPUs_with_AVX-512) was an adaptation of the vector ISA developed for Larrabee and sold commercially in first-gen Xeon Phi, Knight's Corner).

Comment: Hi Peter, as usual many thanks for the help

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't know there used to be x86 based GPUs.

Comment: @SimonGoater: They never made it to marked, but yes, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larrabee_(microarchitecture) was aimed at GPGPU and *actual* GPU; I've read that some engineering samples / prototypes existed with video outputs.